# Javascript testing within django project, with CI and coverage

Tags: javascript, django, testing, continuous-integration, hudson

I'm working on a Django project that by design is pretty javascript heavy. For the serverside code we try to have decent test coverage by using unittests, and on a slightly higher level have tests using the Django testclient. We have a Hudson/Jenkins server running for CI, with stuff set up more or less along the lines of [this article](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2010/03/08/django-and-hudson-ci-day-1/), giving us test pass and coverage stats.

I would like to have something similar for our javascript too. I would like to be able to test on unit-test level, but also on integration/acceptance test level. The latter would require a full DOM JS environment and a django server that's running. Ideally I would want to somehow use the Django test client so I can set up the serverstate in the way I'm used to for Django tests. I would also like to run all of the tests from the CI server, which would require some sort of headless browser environment (server is Ubuntu without a desktop environment).

I have found a bunch of stuff, but a lot feels like it couldn't run on the CI server. Also the integration with Django often isn't great, and don't do good test isolation for the server environment. Finally I would ideally like something that works at a pretty good pace, to keep my test/code cycle as quick as possible.

Are there frameworks that do what I want or has anybody managed to cobble together a solution that comes close? And are there any established best practices in general for doing good javascript testing in combination with Django (i.e. are there any recommended approaches from the django folks I'm missing)?

Comment: "Cobble together" is about right for me.  I've used jruby's celerity and zombie.js to do what you're asking, but never found the solutions very satisfying.  There was always something browser-specific that had to be hand-tested anyway.

Comment: same question here. I'll be looking at the javascript stuff in [django-jenkins](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins) to see if that can do part of it.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlUNIT looks like it might do some of what you need (ie a headless browser that supports JavaScript). It shouldn't be *too* hard to rig this up against a 'runserver' style management command that also dumps coverage on exit.

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: +1 for direction, but their bugtracker contents are a bit scary though: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=47038&atid=448266

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) a Python implementation of [Phantom.JS](http://phantomjs.org/). I provides an extension for django built on to of the upcoming [LiveServerTestCase](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/testcases.py#L947).

It relies on PyQt4, so you'll have to copy it to your project's virtualenv.